# websphere properties file

Tags: properties, websphere, datasource

I want to store the datasource properties and the queue properties in separate property file, so WebSphere Application Server will load this properties during sturtup. Is it possible to create such property file for WAS 6.1 and 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The nearest you can get is to run a wsadmin script which will use the properties file to update the server configuration using the `AdminTask.applyConfigProperties()` command, but there's no way to set up the server to run such a script automatically on startup.